# Document sets in SharePoint App for Android

Tags: document-set, android

I downloaded the SharePoint App for Android and tried to access my files. I can see them in normal document libraries. But whenever I enter a document set, the files are not shown. 
Is this a common problem? Did anybody experience the same behaviour? Are doc sets supported by the app?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could configure a `new view`>under the `Folders` header select `show all items without folders`.

Are your documents visible this way?  If so, you could try setting this as the mobile view.

Here is a related post on a [similar subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925501/need-to-see-flat-view-of-document-set-in-sharepoint-2010).

Comment: I would actually like to see folders. My document sets contain folders and I would like to see those in a regular structure...